# Exit code -1 in terminal but code=1 in output when running "Hello world" in c++ Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Before I begin I want to address the fact that I am EXTREMELY new to computer sciences and I do not have any background in technology or technical jargon/term words. I'm mainly an artist/writer and trying to find my way into this realm of technology.
I am in a class for learning C++ but my teacher has not helped the entire time, so I thought turning to here would help.

This mess is kind of confusing, at least for me as a newbie, but when I try to imput the Hello World command from my Visual Studio Code program (C++), I get confusing messages about the code not working.

When I first hit run, the popup appears saying "The preLaunchTask 'C/C++:gcc.exe build active file' terminated with exit code -1"

I click show errors and the Problems menu says there is no issues.

I click the output window and it says, per quote

```
[Running] cd "c:\Users\isabe\OneDrive\Desktop\All game and coding stuff\c++ coding\" && g++ .cpp -o  && "c:\Users\isabe\OneDrive\Desktop\All game and coding stuff\c++ coding\"
g++: error: missing filename after '-o'

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.114 seconds"
```

In the terminal it looks like a big mess of code looking through my files but at the end it says

```
undefined reference to 'std::cout'collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Build finished with errors
The terminal process terminated with exit code : -1"
```

The code was input directly from the book I was told to purchase by my teacher as just a test to check if the compiler was working, no clue what I'm really doing so I'm kind of at a loss.

Comment: *my teacher has not helped the entire time* they rarely do unless you approach them with carefully researched and well worded questions. You'll find similar here. Looks like you have misconfigured Visual Studio Code. This is unfortunately easy to do. Note how in `g++ .cpp -o `  the name of the cpp file is missing along with the name of the output file. My VSCode-fu is weak, so I can't tell you how to fix this, but can I talk you into using [a more-easily configured development tool](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/)?

Comment: Clarification to above comment: This is a pretty decent first question. It could do with less chaff, we don't need any backstory, but otherwise it contains all of the information needed to understand the problem. Likely someone will come along shortly and tell you which JSON files you need to paste into the question so that they can show you where the configuration error is, but if you already knew which JSON file was wrong, you wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: `.cpp` is a bug

Comment: `All game and coding stuff\c++ coding`  In `c` or `c++` you should avoid putting spaces in paths or filenames. This may cause you some difficultly building because most compliers for both languages are command line / shell utilities and on the shell / terminal a space separates arguments causing your build tool to have to quote to combine it back to 1 argument. Even in 2022 the quoting will fail from time to time.

Comment: If you are using the default VSCode building (not using an extension like code-runner) we need to see your `tasks.json` file. You may want to read the official tutorial here: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) which explains the 3 json files and also tells you to install MinGW using msys2

Comment: Vscode is definitely not great for c++ beginners, visual studio will do a lot more for you, you can just create a project paste in your code and press run, no configuration need, you don't even need to install a separate compiler (and, depending on version, mingw has its fair share of problems on Windows)